# Disabling OR enabling visibility of a class from another class in css

Tags: css

I am experiencing difficulties in enabling the visibility of a class when I hover over its parent class in CSS. i.e. I want to enable the submenu class on hover effect over the menu class.My html code for this is as follows:

```
<li class="menu"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And the corresponding css is as follows :

```
    .subMenu
{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.menu:hover .subMenu
{
    display:inherit;
    visibility:visible;    
}
```

Now  I have difficulties with the hover effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7SpPJ/ is this what u need

Comment: @Rahul but adding elements between li's is not valid. all the inner elements should statrt inside the li or ouside the ul

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the sub `menu ul` inside the main `li`. Currently it is outside the `li` so it is not visible on hover.

Change your html like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VSEHr/1/)

Comment: @user1957491 ur wlcm but y is my a/c link here :)

Comment: dun't know.. just dragged and dropped.. new here . dun't know how to use.. :(